# Qbs, non-existance base profile error

Tags: c++, qt, qbs

I'm learning Qbs by compiling a Qt based open source library. I set my Qbs project as below.

```
import qbs 1.0

Project {
    Product {
        name: "communi"
        type: "dynamiclibrary"

        files: [
            "include/IrcCore/irc.h",
            "include/IrcCore/irccommand.h",
             ... ,
            "src/util/irccommandqueue.cpp",
            "src/util/irccompleter.cpp",
            "src/util/irclagtimer.cpp",
            "src/util/ircpalette.cpp",
            "src/util/irctextformat.cpp",
            "src/util/irctoken.cpp",
            "src/util/ircutil.cpp"
        ]

        Depends { name: "cpp" }
        Depends { name: "Qt.core" }
        Depends { name: "Qt.widgets" }
    }
}
```

I invoke Qbs as follows;

```
qbs build profile:qt
```

and got the error message below

```
ERROR: Profile "qt" has a non-existent base profile "msvc".
```

What am I doing wrong? I did the configuration as explained in the manual.
I'm on Windows 10 x64, using Qbs 1.9 and Qt 5.9.1.

The list of my profiles is as below;

```
>> qbs config --list profiles
profiles.MSVC2017-x64.cpp.compilerVersion: "19.11.25507"
profiles.MSVC2017-x64.cpp.toolchainInstallPath: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/HostX64/x64"
profiles.MSVC2017-x64.qbs.architecture: "x86_64"
profiles.MSVC2017-x64.qbs.targetOS: "windows"
profiles.MSVC2017-x64.qbs.toolchain: "msvc"
profiles.MSVC2017-x64_x86.cpp.compilerVersion: "19.11.25507"
profiles.MSVC2017-x64_x86.cpp.toolchainInstallPath: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/HostX64/x86"
profiles.MSVC2017-x64_x86.qbs.architecture: "x86"
profiles.MSVC2017-x64_x86.qbs.targetOS: "windows"
profiles.MSVC2017-x64_x86.qbs.toolchain: "msvc"
profiles.MSVC2017-x86.cpp.compilerVersion: "19.11.25507"
profiles.MSVC2017-x86.cpp.toolchainInstallPath: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/HostX86/x86"
profiles.MSVC2017-x86.qbs.architecture: "x86"
profiles.MSVC2017-x86.qbs.targetOS: "windows"
profiles.MSVC2017-x86.qbs.toolchain: "msvc"
profiles.MSVC2017-x86_x64.cpp.compilerVersion: "19.11.25507"
profiles.MSVC2017-x86_x64.cpp.toolchainInstallPath: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/HostX86/x64"
profiles.MSVC2017-x86_x64.qbs.architecture: "x86_64"
profiles.MSVC2017-x86_x64.qbs.targetOS: "windows"
profiles.MSVC2017-x86_x64.qbs.toolchain: "msvc"
profiles.qt.baseProfile: "msvc"
profiles.qt.preferences.qbsSearchPaths: "C:/Users/tembo/AppData/Roaming/QtProject/qbs/1.9.0/profiles/qt"
profiles.x86_64-w64-mingw32.cpp.toolchainInstallPath: "C:/MinGW/bin"
profiles.x86_64-w64-mingw32.qbs.targetOS: "windows"
profiles.x86_64-w64-mingw32.qbs.toolchain: ["mingw", "gcc"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the qbs config output you pasted, you don't have a profile called "msvc" (the example in the manual assumes you do). Please use one of the existing ones, for instance MSVC2017-x64.